# Apostrophes with PDO prepare and magic_quotes off

Tags: php, pdo, quotes

given the code

```
$stmnt= $pdo->prepare ("insert into books (author, title, purchased, completed,
price, format) VALUES (:author, :title, :purchased, :completed,:price, :format)"); 
  $stmnt->bindParam (':author',    $author);
  $stmnt->bindParam (':title',     $title);
  $stmnt->bindParam (':purchased', $purchased);
  $stmnt->bindParam (':price',     $price);
  $stmnt->bindParam (':completed', $completed);
  $stmnt->bindParam (':format',    $format);
```

what is stored in the MySQL table for the string `dog's`

Is it `dog's`  or is it `dog\'s`?

PHPAdmin says `dog\'s`

In either case when I return the string from MySQL using PDO I only see the characters in the string up to but not including the apostrophe e.g. `dog`

What do I need to do to the string to display properly?

`phpinfo` reports that `magic_quotes` are off.

**Edit**

I've found that if I manually remove the slash using PHPMyAdmin and then use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars things work fine.  Now I just have to figure out why the backslash is being stored in the sql table.

PHPInfo says magic_quotes_gpc and magic_quotes_runtime are off (local value and master value) so there is something else inserting the backslash in the table.

Comment: It's not PDO's doing: you may have [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled.

Comment: Did the variables otherwise get preprocessed before that query? Also show the output code, and in which context you intended to display it.

Comment: If you only see characters up to but not including the quote, that sounds like you're using it inside something like an HTML attribute, without properly escaping it.  As in `"value='$value'"` when you need to use `"value='" . htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES) . "'"`

Comment: As mentioned, show your _output_ code, as that's probably faulty.

Comment: The output code has been changed to add $title = htmlspecialchars ($book->title,ENT_QUOTES);

This soles the problem with the string being cutoff but I still had a problem with backslash being added. I found that my post function (which was written prior to using PDO) was adding the backslash.

Thanks all.  As so often happens, just getting me thinking straighter solves the problem.